# How to create XML file in blackberry 10 device document directory through cascade QML?

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, cascade

I have `XML data` stored in `QString/QByteArray`, I want to write that xml data in new `sample.xml` file and save that file in device document directory.

Anyone please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QXmlStreamWriter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qxmlstreamwriter.html#QXmlStreamWriter-3). [Here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/stable/examples/xml/xmlstreamlint/main.cpp#line100) you can find an official example which reads from a device and then writes that out. You could slightly modify this to allow to read from your QString/QByteArray by the appropriate construct if I understand your query correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
QFile file(QDir::currentPath() + "/shared/documents/yourfile.txt");
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << "DATA HERE \n";
}
```